# A positive real number $a$ and any natural number $n$, prove that there exists one and only one positive real number such that $\epsilon^n=a$

Tags: calculus

> Given a positive real number $a$ and any natural number $n$, prove that there exists one and only one positive real number $\epsilon$ such that $$\epsilon^n=a$$

**My work**

Let $$f(x)=x^n-a$$
$$f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$$

For $x>0, \;\;f'(x)>0 \;\;\;\forall n$

So I deduced from this that if there is a positive root, then it will be the only one. But how did I prove the rest:

(1) There is a real root

(2) The real root is positive

Comment: (1) You can construct this statement; it's not clear what you're assuming, but you can use some method of bisection for which you can always find this root (e.g. start on the interval $x \in (0, a)$ and bisect appropriately).

(2) That the real root is positive follows from $x^n$ being monotonic and $f(0) < 0$.

(3) There *can* be negative roots. Consider $x^2 = 1$.

Comment: (1)I don't need to _find_ the root. Only that it is positive and it is the only one. (2) But what if all its roots are negative. The function is  not monotonic for $x<0$ (3) You are right. The equation may have negative roots.

Comment: On (1), it's simple to just give a constructive argument; this also just follows from (2). On (2) you know the function diverges from $x=0, f(0)<0$ to $x\to\infty, f(x)\to \infty > 0$. Since that's true and $f(0) < 0$ then it must have some value $f(x) = 0$, $x>0$ since you know $f$ is continuous as you know it's differentiable. The fact that it's unique follows from monotonicity.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Yep, no worries!

Comment: If any answer simpler than calculus works, how about just setting $\epsilon$ to the $n \text{th-root}$ of $a$?

Comment: @MikeMathMan I think the idea was showing that there *is* an $n$th-root and that the positive branch of such a function is well-defined and unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer:

Proving existence of (2) $\implies$ (1). In order to prove (2), all we have to do is prove that there exists *a* positive root, since by strict monotonicity, we know it will be unique. As such, since $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, and we know that $f(0) = -a < 0$ and we also know $f(x)\to \infty$ whenever $x \to \infty$ then there exists at least one $x\in (0, \infty)$ such that $f(x)=0$ as we know $f$ is continuous (by its differentiability). This immediately proves (2) and therefore (1).

Answer (score 2):

The Intermediate value theorem for $f$ immediately gives you that there exists a real positive root on $[0,max(\{1,a\})]$. But you have to show that $f$ is continuous.

If you want to prove it more elementary you will have to use the completeness axiom of the reel numbers and look at the supremum of the set $\{\epsilon : \epsilon^n -a < 0\}$

Comment: The problem says that $\epsilon$ is positive